# How to read Firebase Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, firebase

I am running a polymer starter kit app and I need a firebase connection, but I don't know why the browser say that require is undefined.

```
$ npm install firebase --save

var Firebase = require("firebase");
```

[image: error]

Comment: Jim O'Brien's answer is excellent. However, you can use the web version of Firebase which does not need the require function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `require` is a function provided by node.js's 'module' module. It is not part of the ES5 spec, and so it is not natively available in web browsers.

In order to load modules using `require`, you will have to use a web bundler (like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)). This will  bundle together all of the JS in your project into a single file, automatically handling calls to `require`.

I'd recommend reading [*Getting started with Webpack*](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/) to get you on your way.